# Observer not removed when leaving Charts VC with iOS-Charts 2.2.3?

Tags: observers, ios-charts

I am working on adding some graphs to my app and had a working version with iOS-Charts 2.1.4. After updating to iOS-Charts 2.2.3 I get the following error when going back from the View Controller containing my CombinedChartView:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x168c5a00 of class Charts.CombinedChartView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x171366c0> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x15d0dda0: Observer: 0x168c5a00, Key path: bounds, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x15d1b090>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x15d17a10: Observer: 0x168c5a00, Key path: frame, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x15db49b0>)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x217b62eb 0x20f82dff 0x217b6231 0x21f60095 0x20f9d3cd 0x216c9921 0x217774c7 0x216c9bb9 0x216c99ad 0x22943af9 0x259b5fb5 0xf7ed1 0x2137c873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Note: I do not voluntarily register any observers in this VC.

Anybody seeing the same with latest version of iOS-Charts? Great graph library by the way!

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to @Wingzero's suggestions!

So my issue was that the ChartViewBase.init() method was called twice, thus registering the observers twice but deinit() was only called once so there was a duplicate set of observers left hanging.

The reason for the double init() call is that I started working with the iOS-Charts lib on v.2.1 and at that time needed to manually initialise the CombinedChartView in my VC's viewDidLoad() (or so I thought). With the update to iOS-Charts 2.2.3 (or Swift 2?) this is not needed anymore and will lead to double initialisation and thus one instance of the ChartViews left hanging.

Hope this might help someone else following the same 2.1 -> 2.2.3 update path for iOS-Charts. I've got to say, I highly recommend the iOS-Charts as a graph library for iOS. This was just my error.

Also note that cocoaPod doesn't know about the 2.2 version of the lib yet.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what's your code problem, but it seems like your library is broken.

iOS-charts did remove the observer in deinit():

```
deinit
{
    self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds")
    self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")
}
```

However your trace is

`Charts.CombinedChartView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it`

It's a paradox. You may want to check your library. when the combined chart is deinited, the observer should be removed. You can also add a break pint in `deinit` to debug.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you're right but I'm not sure what / how it could have gone wrong. 
I haven't modified any of the library's file.
The removal of the observers is there in the deinit() method of ChartViewBase.swift.

Comment: I have also checked out a completely clean project and added the library again and I have exactly the same result.
One possibly suspect thing happen when I add the Charts.xcodeproj to my project and then go to my target's Embedded Binaries to add the Charts.framework, I get 6 different Charts.framework. 2 iOS ones, 2 tvOS and 2 OS X ones. 
Not sure why they're all in double. And not sure how that could be linked to the non removal of observer (I only add 1 of the iOS ones off course).

Comment: I'll try the cocoaPods install on a fresh project see if that behaves any different

Comment: well I suggest you add breakpoints in deinit and debug it. it never can be deinited but not calling deinit.

Comment: BTW, you mentioned you have 2 iOS framework? one is enough

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try that as well and report.

Comment: sure, if issues still there and you have no idea, maybe fire an issue on github page.

Comment: re: 2iOS framework. Yes, that's why I thought it was odd. I only add one of the 2 to my projects but the target -> Embedded Binaries window offers 2 of each.

Comment: CocoaPods installs version 2.1.3 of the Charts library by default. Why not the latest 2.2.3?

Comment: @Litome I don't know, I don't use pods.. search github old issues, there should be answers